# How do I debug a flask library specific error related to flask-mail

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am working on a website that sends an email upon request. In this email is a pdf attachment. When I go ahead and run the associated code to send the email, at the part where the pdf file is to be attached I recieve the error

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 10: invalid start byte

On windows the associated block of code runs fine and I am able send the email sucessfully with the attachment. I am currently testing my code on linux as I am hoping to push my code onto a debian server in the future.
Therefore, this bug occurs right now on Ubuntu 18.04, but not on Windows 10, where I originally wrote the code.

The associated code is

```
@staticmethod
def send_custom_email(email_addr, pdf_link):
    msg = Message("Theatre - Ticket", sender="notreal@gmail.com")
    msg.html ="Attached below is your ticket. Enjoy the Show !"

    with open(pdf_link) as fp:  
        msg.attach(pdf_link, "application/pdf", fp.read())
        msg.add_recipient(email_addr)
        mail.send(msg)
```

Please not that I am using the flask_mail library

I am trying my best to debug this code and figure out why I am getting this error.
I have tried modifying my code to

```
msg.attach(pdf_link, "application/pdf", fp.read().decode('utf-8')

and 
msg.attach(pdf_link, "application/pdf", fp.read().encode('utf-8')
```

to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be base64-encoding that PDF file before attaching it? Or does `flask_mail` do that for you?

Comment: flask_mail does it for me. I generate the pdf file with reportlab (a python library). I guess i need to figure out reportlab's encoding